# How to Translate Column values from french to english language using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry

I have a dataframe with one column having all the values in French. I would like to know how to translate all those values at a time to English language using Pyspark and in Palantir platform.

Comment: pyspark does not have a translation service. you can, however, use python packages (e.g. `translate`) for the translation which can be used as an UDF in pyspark